# Calculate the number of different columns between rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a Pandas DataFrame filled with various data. Some of it are categorical data(stored in the DataFrame as 'object' type).

I want to calculate the number of fields(columns) in which one row differs with all the other rows.

Example shape of the data(columns are name 'i', 'j', 'k'; the first number is index):

```
  i  j  k 
1 a  b  c
2 a  d  f
3 b  d  f
4 a  b  f
```

And the additional row that I want to compare with(index pro forma):

```
0 a b f
```

The result I'm looking for is something like:

```
[1,1,2,0]
```

Because 0 and 1 differ at 'k', 0 and 2 differ at 'j', 0 and 3 differ at 'i' and 'j', and 0 and 4 don't differ at all.

I am going to do this quite often, so I need a fast version. I already have one that does it by looping, but that's slow; I need something faster, so I am trying to come up with a vectorized version.

Please note that the dataframe will contain other columns(numerical); the supplied data does not mention them, but you can assume that there would be some other columns(e.g. 'h' which would contain int64). We want to ignore those columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadcast, compare, and sum up the result:

```
diff = (df != np.array(['a', 'b', 'f'])).sum(1).tolist()

print(diff)
[1, 1, 2, 0]
```

If your data is in a single row DataFrame `s`, then your solution will look like this:

```
df.ne(s.iloc[0].values, axis=1).sum(1).tolist()
```

Comment: This question is lost on me.  +1 for matching output (-:

Comment: Good answer man , maybe you can add `df.ne(s.iloc[0],axis=1).sum(1)`

Comment: That was great! That got me the required speed-up. Thank you a ton.